# Why xerces shows me "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid content was found starting with element"?

Tags: java, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

I created a test XML that is attached below and that I validate against the following XSD:

> http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/bd/20171213/validation/bd-axes.xsd

And it results in the following java error:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 53; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/bd/20180919/dictionary/bd-data-ext2":MessageSourceType}'. One of '{"http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance":item, "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance":tuple, "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance":context, "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance":unit, "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase":footnoteLink}' is expected.
>           at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)

Can you please explain why? 
How should I analyse these kind of errors, I always have a hard time understanding these errors.

Details:
I create a javax.xml.validation.Validator instance through

```
final SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
factory.setResourceResolver(resourceResolver);
validator = factory.newSchema(createSchemaSources()).newValidator()
validator.validate(createdXML)
```

Created XML:

```
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:bd-domain-members="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/bd/20171213/dictionary/bd-domain-members" xmlns:xbrl-syntax-extension="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/2011/xbrl/xbrl-syntax-extension" xmlns:bd-t="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/bd/20171213/dictionary/bd-tuples" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:bd-t-ext2="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/bd/20180919/dictionary/bd-tuples-ext2" xmlns:xbrldt="http://xbrl.org/2005/xbrldt" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:XLink="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/XLink" xmlns:bd-domains="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/bd/20171213/validation/bd-domains" xmlns:bd-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/bd/20171213/dictionary/bd-data" xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi" xmlns:nl-common-data="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/sbr/20170515/dictionary/nl-common-data" xmlns:bd-i-ext2="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/bd/20180919/dictionary/bd-data-ext2" xmlns:bd-axes-ext2="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/bd/20180919/validation/bd-axes-ext2" xmlns:bd-domain-members-ext2="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/bd/20180919/dictionary/bd-domain-members-ext2" xmlns:linkbase="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:bd-axes="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/bd/20171213/validation/bd-axes" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:lang="nl">
   <linkbase:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt12/bd/20180919/entrypoints/bd-rpt-tsl-2019.xsd" xlink:arcrole="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink/properties/linkbase"/>
   <xbrli:context id="cc_371">
      <xbrli:entity>
         <xbrli:identifier scheme="www.belastingdienst.nl/identificatie">610946109</xbrli:identifier>
      </xbrli:entity>
      <xbrli:period>
         <xbrli:startDate>2019-01-01</xbrli:startDate>
         <xbrli:endDate>2019-12-31</xbrli:endDate>
      </xbrli:period>
   </xbrli:context>
   <bd-i:SoftwarePackageName contextRef="cc_371">BSTYAYyXqdLDfsqYyaKvamVvLqdjek</bd-i:SoftwarePackageName>
   <bd-i:SoftwarePackageVersion contextRef="cc_371">hP</bd-i:SoftwarePackageVersion>
   <bd-i:SoftwareVendorAccountNumber contextRef="cc_371">vWRSMzSI</bd-i:SoftwareVendorAccountNumber>
   <bd-i:TaxReturnMessageType contextRef="cc_371">0084</bd-i:TaxReturnMessageType>
   <bd-i-ext2:MessageSourceType contextRef="cc_371">48</bd-i-ext2:MessageSourceType>
   <bd-i-ext2:MessageIdentification contextRef="cc_371">ottZieoUAieKCcAFQHpF</bd-i-ext2:MessageIdentification>
   <bd-i-ext2:TaxPayerSignatureIndication contextRef="cc_371">1</bd-i-ext2:TaxPayerSignatureIndication>
   <bd-i:CohabitationPeriodTaxYearEnd contextRef="cc_371">2018-05-10+02:00</bd-i:CohabitationPeriodTaxYearEnd>
</xbrli:xbrl>
```

Comment: Basically it is say the element it found was MessageSourceType but it was expecting something else first, e.g item, tuple, context, unit or footnoteLink  (usually when it has a list like that all but the last one are optional, but the last one is required).